# Plusclient.builder class cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I am new to android studio and i want to login using google signin credentials. I have kept all the required dependencies and compilesdkversion with 19.1.0.
It show the following error::

```
Error:(78, 31) error: cannot find symbol class Builder
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'. 
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Suggestion required to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: it works on eclipse but not on studio. No solution found for studio.

Comment: use GoogleApiClient instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is deprecated.Also the code reference is not updated in Android studio. Use Google Api client. Refer [here](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) It working for me!!

Answer (score 1):

The `PlusClient` class is deprecated (although you won't see the strike through warning on Android Studio).I tried to use the `Create LoginActivity` option in Android Studio for creating a new activity and I got this error.What I did was change my `Google play services` version from the current, which was

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

as at time of writing to:

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
```

and resynced my project and it work. It is strongly adviced that you use the `GoogleApiClient` class instead though.Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't download the Google Play services, if not then install them from SDK Manager -> Extras -> Google Play Services.

If the problem still exist then do

step 5 of [Google+ Quickstart:](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android)

5. Import the Google Play Services library project.

Select File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
Select Browse.... Enter /extras/google/google_play_services/.
Select google-play-services_lib. Click Finish to import.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: The problem occurred in android Studio so it would be great if you keep the limitation to android studio.